# How to send email password when creating a new user by API in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, api

It is possible to create a new user by API with the following line:

```
$user_id = wp_insert_user( $user_data );
```

I wonder how to send the newly created user an email that contains his password? Is there any function in Wordpress API that handles this job or should I create and send an email by myself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you are generating the password and adding it to the `$user_data` array?

If not, you can use this to generate a password -

```
$this->password = wp_generate_password(6, false);
$user_data['user_pass'] = $this->password;
```

And while there probably is a way of hooking in to the generic WP send password email, I just use my own. That way, I can customise the content, and make it look like other emails from my site.

Note that I have set up a Class for registration, so if you have not, you will need to remove instances of `$this->`.

```
function prepare_email(){

        $confirmation_to = $_REQUEST['email_address'];
        $confirmation_subject = 'Confirmation - Registration to My Site';
        $confirmation_message = 'Hi '.$_REQUEST['first_name'].',<br /></br />Thank you for registering with My Site. Your account has been set up and you can log in using the following details -<br /><br />'
            .'<strong>Username:</strong> '.$_REQUEST['username']
            .'<br /><strong>Password:</strong> '.$this->password
            .'<br /><br />Once you have logged in, please ensure that you visit the Site Admin and change you password so that you don\'t forget it in the future.';
        $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0'."\r\n";
        $headers.= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'."\r\n";
        $confirmation_headers = $headers.'From: My Site <no-reply@mysite.com>'."\r\n";

        $this->form_for_email = compact('confirmation_to', 'confirmation_subject', 'confirmation_message', 'confirmation_headers');

    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing your code. Yes, using my own email would help us to make all emails standardized.

Answer (score 35):

As David guessed (but didn't specify), there is some functionality inside Wordpress to do this: [`wp_new_user_notification($user_id, $user_pass)`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_new_user_notification).

So, rewriting the above code, it should look like this (*code has been edited after parameter deprecation in 4.3.1*):

```
$user_id = wp_insert_user( $user_data );
wp_new_user_notification( $user_id, null, 'both' );
```

**Edit:** Please also see @ale's comment below.

Comment: is this deprecated now?

Comment: @AndrewWelch I read sth about this as well; but it still seems to be in the source of the (currently latest) WordPress 4.5.2. When I checked the source I found out that just the possibility to pass a password to the function was deprecated. In stead, WordPress will now generate a new reset password key for the user, and sends the reset password link via email to the user.

Note: i have not tried this yet (was for research purposes only as preparation for a project). I will confirm (or someone else please do) when we'll be touching this.

Comment: Not working in my case. Might be because i am using the latest version of wordpress. My code is in page template

Comment: According to do the docs (link in my answer), it's available since WP 2.0 and not deprecated. What exactly didn't work? Did you see any errors / log entries?

Comment: Since 4.3.1. the second parameter of this function was deprecated. Now you should pass 'null' as a value. So password should not be passed as an argument to this function. And as a third parameter we have the '$notify' option that can accepts: admin, user, both. This parameter is specifying to whom the notification e-mail should be sent.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is now obsolete. The answer using `wp_new_user_notification()` works and will send a WordPress-like mail.

Still, you might want to send your own mail as David Gard suggested. Here is a bit of code that does this. You can use it as a function, or as a method in a class.

```
/**
 * Send mail with a reset password link
 *
 * @param  int $user_id  User ID
 */
function notify_new_user( $user_id )
{
    $user = get_userdata( $user_id );

    $subject   = '[website] Connection details';
    $mail_from = get_bloginfo('admin_email');
    $mail_to   = $user->user_email;
    $headers   = array(
        'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8',
        'From: ' . $mail_from,
    );

    $key = get_password_reset_key( $user );
    if ( is_wp_error( $key ) ) {
        return;
    }
    $url_password = network_site_url( "wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$key&login=" . rawurlencode( $user->user_login ) );

    $body = '<p>HTML body in your own style.</p>';
    $body .= '<p>It must include the login identifier: ' . $user->user_login . '</p>';
    $body .= '<p>And the link: ' . $url_password . '</p>';
    
    wp_mail( $mail_to, $subject, $body, $headers );
}
```

If you don’t want to have the HTML content in the function, you can use a template engine. Here is an example you could add to the above code.

```
// Set up Mustache
$path = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/mails';
$dir  = wp_get_upload_dir();
$m    = new \Mustache_Engine( [
    'cache'           => $dir['basedir'] . '/mustache_cache',
    'loader'          => new \Mustache_Loader_FilesystemLoader( $path ),
    'partials_loader' => new \Mustache_Loader_FilesystemLoader( $path . '/layouts' ),
] );

// Variable data in the mail
$data['mail']['title'] = $subject;          // {{mail.title}}
$data['identifier']    = $user->user_login; // {{identifier}}
$data['url-password']  = $url_password;     // {{url-password}}

$body = $m->render( 'mail-template-new-user', $data );
```

[Mustache tags documentation](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php/wiki/Mustache-Tags).