# Creating user with wp_insert_user & generated password - best way to notify new user including password?

Tags: php, wordpress

In a custom PHP page after a Paypal transaction is completed, I'm creating a WP user based off the information they've entered.  As it was, the wp_new_user_notification sent an email with "To set your password, visit the following address" link which seemed sloppy and unnecessary - and implied a forgotten password (at least on the bloated site I'm trying to change - that may not be the default behavior.)

Alternatively, I just want to create the user and a WP generated password, then send them the details using something like this (I've omitted some non-relevant code):

```
$password = wp_generate_password( 12, true );
$userdata = array(
    'user_login'  =>  $email,
    'user_pass'    =>  $password,
);
$user_id = wp_insert_user( $userdata ) ;
if ( ! is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) {
    wp_new_user_notification( $user_id, null, both ); 
}
```

Is there a practical way to use wp_new_user_notification to send the generated password in plain text so the receipient knows what it is?  Or do I need to make the custom PHP page send a custom e-mail while I have the non-hashed version available?

Ultimately, I just want to create the user and sent them a 'welcome' email with their username and the generated password, just not sure the best approach and/or if I should be using the wp_new_user_notification function or not.  The code above still sends the default user notification email that I'm aware I can change via plugin - but not in such a way I can include the plain-text password as far as I can tell.

Note: there's an older Q&A at [How to send email password when creating a new user by API in Wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509575/how-to-send-email-password-when-creating-a-new-user-by-api-in-wordpress) that seems to cover it, but the plain text password appears to be depreciated?

Comment: Ideally its never a good idea to send password in plain text, You can have a reset link generated to asking them to update their password.

Comment: Thanks lucky, it's not really an over-sensitive login though, and whats the point of being able to generate a WP password if there's no way to pass it along?

Comment: wp doesnt save the plain text version anywhere, it hashes it and stores that (one way hashing). So theres no way to pull it from the db, unless you save it somewhere (in a global if there is no redirect before you intend to use, or in the db) but make sure you clean up afterwards